# Is it permissible to work as a sales rep in this case?

Tags: sharia, money, work, islamic-scholar, finance

**Assalamu Alikoum**

I work as a sales representative (I get a commission for each deal closed) for a marketing agency and this agency promotes projects and each project is different, some projects have 2D drawings or 3D or sometimes there are projects with no drawings, etc...

My question is if I get clients for this marketing agency, is the money earned from the commission halal or haram or do I bear a sin if I do so or I have no direct relationship with them?

**Jazzakumo Allahu Kahyran**

Answer (score 1):

Islamic opinion on the drawing of living things or drawings of things that can represent living things varies among different scholars.

**Common Opinions**

- All drawings of living things are haram.
- Drawing of living things omitting some part where it wouldn't make it a living thing anymore is halal. Such as drawing the human body without a head.
- Drawing living things (2d) is not haram and only makruh.

  - https://seekersguidance.org/answers/maliki-fiqh/the-maliki-view-on-pictures-of-humans-and-animals/
- Drawing of living things is permissible as long as the drawing isn't something haram or meant to be used for haram (such as worshipping, etc).

  - Sheikh Yusuf-Al-Qaradawi's fatwa in Arabic regarding the drawing of living things being permissible: https://hawramani.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/fatwa_drawing.pdf

***Tolerance of Drawings depicting living things***

Furthermore, Prophet Muhammad (SAW) himself and Islamic history  tolerated drawings of living things and I'll list some evidences for you:

**Evidences**

- Prophet Sulayman had statues built for him. If statues were inherently evil and disliked by God, how could a prophet do such a thing?
- The Prophet (peace and blessings of God be upon him) and his Companions used Byzantine coinage that had human portraits on them, yet there is no mention whatsoever of the Prophet (peace and blessings of God be upon him) disliking them or considering it impermissible to use such coinage.
- The highly respected Successor al-Qasim b. Muhammad, one of Medina’s Seven Jurists, considered drawings of living things to be permissible.
- The Prophet (peace and blessings of God be upon him) ordered Aisha to take away a curtain that had the picture of bird on it because “it reminds me of the worldly life”. He did not say it is prohibited or evil–just that it was distracting.
- Aisha used to have a toy horse with wings, the Prophet (peace and blessings of God be upon him) laughed at it and did not say it should be destroyed.
- The Companions did not destroy the paintings and statues in Khosrow’s palaces or in Egypt. Their inaction shows that there was no universal agreement on such things being evil and harmful.

https://hawramani.com/the-evidence-for-the-permissibly-of-drawing-and-painting-in-islam/

**Conclusion**

Working at your current job should be of no issue unless you hold a stricter opinion. Follow the opinion that makes the most sense to you and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, any 2D or 3D image that doesn't depict a human or an animal is halal.

Concerning humans and animals, fiqh differs. I have published an overview on [How can I make my drawings of humans halal?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/68011/how-can-i-make-my-drawings-of-humans-halal/68041#68041).

which is a part of the answer, showing different rulings.

I found a fatwa on a Salafiya site, allowing digital images in general as long as they are not materilised (I have to find it again in a review of this edit) but this is not commonly agreed in the Salafiya fiqh (and I personally don't agree, either).

It's certainly haram to depict images that are offensive, too (like naked images etc.)

You will certainly have to refuse to do things demanded from you if you are sure that it is against God's Will. But it remains difficult to really know whether a restriction is His Will or just a careful fiqh of a scholar who cannot exclude it that it is His Will.

You can also argue that it is better to change an image so that no Muslim thinks that it is offensive. That's a good argument ifever you are in doubt.

It will finally not be the most important issue when you stand before Him: Have faith in Him and do good deeds. And avoid telling lies when you are doing your job.

Comment: Jazzaka Allah Khayran, 

Thanks for your answer, when I talked about projects, I meant NFT (non fungible token) projects and most of those projects have hand drawings whether it was 3D or 2D and each project is different, so my main concern was if it's okay promoting them, my intention is not to promote the drawings or anything but instead, promote the project itself except the drawings have to be clear from haram things such as naked stuffs, etc...